# What are some examples of bound services?

Tags: android, asynchronous, service

I was wondering why would one use a bound service? I get the it provides a "rich client interface" however, since it executes on the UI thread, I suppose one could not run a CPU/IO intensive operation on it, right?

Let me clarify, say I have a bound service StatService that exposes a method - getStats(). This method may perform some network IO. Now once the service is bound to my Activity, I could directly call getStats() however the whole activity would pause as the service is performing a network IO call.

Is the right way to use the bound service, is to launch a Thread within the service and have it perform the network IO while getStats() simply returns a data structure that is asynchronously populated by the Thread?

Comment: I also had this doubt, currently wherever I am using bound services, I have to include a thread inside the service, because when it is bound it uses the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If your service executes in same process as activity, then, yes, you have to create worker threads to do IO/Network tasks. But if you move service in separate process then you won't have to do it. 
Separating service has own pros and cons. For example if your activity is crashed, your service will continue working. But cross-processing transfer is more expensive than directly access in same process.

Comment: What is an example of a service that executes in a separate process? Is started service an example? Also why would I then use a bound service? Wouldn't I simply create a class with a bunch of threads inside it?